# How would I print a multi-line (non-standard) unicode string of text in C++? Updated for Clarity! (hopefully)

Tags: c++, unicode-string

Rewriting this question with a bit more knowledge on what I'm requesting; (Thank you James Risner and Turtle for your assistance, but I didn't word this correctly and got different responses than what was needed)

---

### I am currently in the process of writing a program for my class in which I print out non-standard Unicode characters in a string. These characters are direct copies from a website, and not in u\ #### standard copy, but rather the unicode characters pre-selected. The program I am running this on is Clion, building my program using mingw's ninja build settings.

My issue that I'm experiencing is that my output, rather than the unicode characters, is instead a random array of (I think) unrelated characters. Printing this in Clion's Debug menu outputs the proper output, but printing it in the runtime or in its own external file all output the issue.
**Below is an exact copy of my code (character for character) DO NOT REUSE PLEASE :(**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

static int Range(int start, int end){
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(start,end);
    return dist(rng);
}

int main() {
    system("color 0F");
    HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    int windowSize = 390;
    MoveWindow(consoleWindow, windowSize,windowSize,windowSize,windowSize, TRUE); // This program and the one below it not only locks the window size, but also locks the window at a fixed display pixel length/width
    SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
    ShowScrollBar(GetConsoleWindow(), SB_VERT, 0);
    string name = "\033[91m▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\n\033[92m███╗░░░███╗░█████╗░██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗██╗\n\033[93m████╗░████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║██║\n\033[94m██╔████╔██║██║░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║██║\n\033[95m██║╚██╔╝██║██║░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║██║\n\033[96m██║░╚═╝░██║╚█████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║██║\n\033[91m╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░╚════╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═╝\n\033[92m▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\n";
    float balance = Range(1,50000);
    float withD, cSelect;
    int x = 0;
    while (name[x] != '\0') {

        cout << name[x] << flush;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
        x++;
    }
    Sleep(2);
    std::cout << '\n' << endl;
    string bottomBar = "\033[93m░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░█░\n";
    string systName = "\033[94mModeni Systems LLC";
    cout << "              ";
    cout << systName << "\n";
    std::cout << '\n' << endl;


    int y = 0;
    while (bottomBar[y] != '\0') {

        cout << name[y] << flush;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
        y++;
    }
    string Input;
    cout << "\n           \033[92mPlease Input your Name...\n\n              ";
    getline(cin, Input);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "          Welcome " << Input << "!" << endl;
    cout << " Please select a number from the options below!\n" << endl;
    cout << bottomBar << endl;
    cout << "         1.)  View your Balance\n         2.)  Make a withdrawal\n         3.)  Deposit\n         4.)  Customer Support\n         5.)  Log Out Securely\n" << endl;
    cout << bottomBar << endl;
    cin >> cSelect;
    while(cSelect != 5){
        if(cSelect==1){
            cout << "Your current balance is... " << balance << " dollars!\n \n" <<  endl;
            cout << "Please select a number from the options given below!\n" << endl;
            cout << bottomBar << endl;
            cout << "        1.)View your Balance\n        2.)Make a withdrawal\n        3.)Deposit\n        4.)Customer Support\n        5.)Log Out Securely" << endl;
            cin >> cSelect;

        } else if(cSelect==2){
            cout << "Please enter the amount you'd like to withdraw!\n" << endl;
            cin >> withD;
            if(withD>balance){
                cout << "Sorry, you do not have that much money! Please try again... " << endl;
            } else if(withD<=balance) {
                balance = balance - withD;
                cout << "Successfully taken out " << withD << " dollars!\n" << "Your new balance is " << balance << " dollars!" << endl;
                cout << "Please select a number from the options given below!\n" << endl;
                cout << bottomBar << endl;
                cout << "        1.)View your Balance\n        2.)Make a withdrawal\n        3.)Deposit\n        4.)Customer Support\n        5.)Log Out Securely" << endl;
                cin >> cSelect;
            }
        } else if(cSelect==3){
            cout << "Please enter the amount you'd like to deposit!" << endl;
            double depAm;
            cin >> depAm;
            balance = balance + depAm;
            cout << "Your new balance is now " << balance << " dollars!" << endl;
            cout << "Please select a number from the options given below!\n" << endl;
            cout << bottomBar << endl;
            cout << "1.)View your Balance\n2.)Make a withdrawal\n3.)Deposit\n4.)Customer Support\n5.)Log Out Securely" << endl;
            cin >> cSelect;
        } else if(cSelect==4){
            cout << bottomBar << "\n" << endl;
            cout << "Hello! This is Modeni's Self-Service Assistant!\n     Please describe your problem below! \n" << endl;
            string proB;
            cin >> proB;
            int chatF;

            chatF = Range(0,5);

            if(chatF==0){
                cout << "We're so sorry to hear that! Please wait as we get you in touch with someone who can help.\n" << endl;
            } else if(chatF==1){
                cout << "Sorry to hear that you're currently having that problem! Please sit tight as we get you in touch with someone who can help.\n" << endl;
            } else if(chatF==2){
                cout << "That's not good! Please wait just a moment as we get you in touch with someone who can help.\n" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Ouch! Just give us a moment while we put you in touch with someone who can help!\n" << endl;
            }
            Sleep(10000);
            string nameSt;
            int nameVar;
            nameVar = Range(0,5);
            if(nameVar == 1)
                nameSt = "Raphael";
            else if(nameVar == 2)
                nameSt = "Marie";
            else if(nameVar == 3)
                nameSt = "Joesph";
            else
                nameSt = "Marian";

            cout << "    \033[94m░█░█ " << nameSt << " has joined the chat █░█░" << endl;

            Sleep(Range(3000,8000));
            cout <<"\n >> Just a moment while I look over your concern.\n" << endl;
            Sleep(Range(3000,8000));
            cout << " >> Alright. I'm sorry you're dealing with this problem right now. Let's put you in touch with one of our call-in agents to assist you further.\n" << endl;
            Sleep(Range(3000,8000));
            cout << " >> Their number is - 1-(918)-335-1300.\n" << endl;
            Sleep(Range(3000,8000));
            cout << " >> Is there anything else I can help you with today? \n" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I am specifically writing this program for windows, and I have yet to find a solid fix without re-writing the entirety of my code.
The intended output is photograph 1, and the actual output is photograph 2. Any and all help is appreciated!

[Photograph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKf2I.png)

[Photograph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZxWj.png)

Comment: This has noting to do with C++, but all to do with what is our terminal and how it is configured. And what is the encoding of our C++ source file.

Comment: Worked perfect on my machine.  What kind of Unix are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to expand your [mcve]. Add more lines of output (and format it a code).

Comment: It's about coding pages either in the compiler or console. Try writing it with u8"<yourstring>". Or redirect the output to a file and copare what character coding is used by the console. In windows (VisualStudio or so) you can also check in document options what is the character coding and set it to utf-8

Comment: To update, building this into an actual executable still displays photograph 2's output of the random jumbled character mess

Comment: Almost certainly your problem is with character encoding.  Clion and the Windows console will use different encodings, so you won't get the same characters printed from the same byte sequence.  And I don't think the Windows console supports escape sequences, at least it never used to.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you happen to know of a Toolchain or perhaps a different IDE that would support unicode exporting and executable building? This program has originated from my python project, where the console was able to properly display the characters used. Could that mean it's a problem with C++ specifically?

Comment: @MarkRansom Don't mind the white character, that was just to pause the console. The photo attached is my python output into the console where you can see the unicode being correctly displayed [link](https://imgur.com/a/YgI2Wcg)

Comment: Oddly enough, my answer is still relevant. There is no universal “ characters are direct copies from a website” encoding. How you print specific Unicode characters depends on your output device. This isn’t a C++ issue. This is a windows terminal encoding issue.

Comment: @JamesRisner I found the "Solution" that allows me to produce a viable output without sacrificing too much. ```setlocale(LC_ALL,  "");``` with wcout and wstring seems to output enough of what I need that I shall not push it further, though I would like to see a formatted list of C++ Unicode-Supported Terminals or Unicode-Supported C++ Formats for console outputting in the future

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your program. There is a problem with your display.

```
% cc -o modeni modeni.cpp -lc++
% ./modeni
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
███╗░░░███╗░█████╗░██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗██╗
████╗░████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║██║
██╔████╔██║██║░░██║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║██║
██║╚██╔╝██║██║░░██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║██║
██║░╚═╝░██║╚█████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║██║
╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░╚════╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═╝
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
% echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

I am using a macOS system and this works with TERM=xterm-256color on both iTerm2 and Terminal.

### What is TERM?

This environment variable advises applications what terminal emulation is required to display characters on screen properly. An application will use the termcap/terminfo database to look up the proper escape sequences to display colors, move or manipulative text on screen, and other effects.

### I only ever see xterm-256color now. Why?

Modern terminal applications assume the output will be in xterm-256color format. Many no longer have an option to choose another format.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no standard way in C++ to process unicode in standard io, and different OSs' default consoles will behave differently if you just make the unicode string as `std::string` to output; E.g. in Windows cmd maybe you need `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` to show UTF-16 strings correctly.

Good news is that in C++23 there will be `<print>` to (hopefully, not definitely so far) help solve this troublesome problem.